# Workflow: delivering items "to a table" (eg in a bar)

Tags: workflow

Having not deployed any Magento solutions before, I'm trying to figure out if Magento really is the sort of solution I'm looking for. I've installed the OS edition on a VM and have been trying to replicate certain workflows.

One that I'm struggling to put together is a "deliver to table" or "deliver to room" option. Not interested in shipping / signing users in / etc.

I like the fact that I can run one store with multiple store fronts. Also out of the box, the product looks very presentable, so I can focus on setting up the functionality and then go back and make it look pretty later. However the "deliver to table" type thing doesn't seem to come naturally to Magento. Am I trying to make a square peg fit a round hole?